# Php PDO Firebird select sum return wrong result

Tags: php, select, pdo, sum, firebird

I have a function that queries a firebird 2.5 database to return a sum of a column.

If I execute this select in a query manager all works fine, but the sum result from php code is wrong.

For example the result value from query manager is 1.205,55 and from php code is 699.785.495,12.

The value of the year colum is correct and the lines returned are correct.

This is the code

```
     $db = getDB();
     $rows = array();

    $sth = $db->prepare("select Sum(D.total) as TOT, D.YEAR from DOCUMENTS D
                          where D.CUST = :custid 
                          GROUP BY D.YEAR ");  


    $custid = $request->getAttribute('custid');
    $sth->bindParam(':custid', $custid, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
    $sth->execute();
    $count = 0;
  
     while ($row = $sth->fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
                      
     $totval = array( 
                   'year' =>  $row->YEAR,  
                   'total ' => number_format($row->TOT, 2, ',', '.')
                    ); 
     

        array_push($rows, $totval);   
        $count++;
        }
```

I think that the error may be related to firebird's dll but the php version is recent (5.6.23) and the firebird dll is loaded properly without any error message.

I made many tests but I can not fix it.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 01/09/16**
This problem occurs only with columns of "NUMERIC" type; with columns "COMPUTED BY" the error does not occur.

**SOLVED 02/09/16**
I've changed the component to manage firebird database from [PDO_FIREBIRD](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-firebird.php) to [Firebird/InterBase Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.ibase.php) and all works fine. The value returned from the query of NUMERIC colums is correct. Probably the PDO_firebird made access to the database with dialect 1 because this is an old problem solved into PDO_firebird.

Comment: What is the dialect of your database?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The dialect is 3. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Do you know how set the dialect 3 when connect to the database using the PDO_firebird ? Thank you.

Comment: For most drivers, the database dialect is used as the connection dialect unless explicitly overridden. However, I don't do PHP, so I don't know the exact behavior of its driver for Firebird. However, funny thing is, this week someone reported a bug with Jaybird (the JDBC driver for Firebird I maintain), and that had also to do with a computed column: Firebird reports both the sub_type and precision of a computed column incorrectly; this might be a similar problem. Upgrading to Firebird 3 might solve it (that still reports the wrong sub_type, but the right precision).